# Is there a difference between PostgreSQL now() and transaction_timestamp() functions?

Tags: postgresql, datetime

In [the official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html), both functions have the same description:

> Current date and time (start of current transaction)

Is there a difference between the two functions, and if not, why do both exist? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`now` and `transaction_timestamp` are equivalent to the SQL standard `current_timestamp`. All report the start time of the transaction.

In terms of transactions, there are two timestamps to think of. the start of the transaction & the time each individual statement is executed. *Conceptually, there is also the end time of the transaction which one can get by running a `select statement_timestamp() trx_end_timestamp` at the very end, just before the commit / rollback.*

If you run the following in psql [copy the whole line & paste into psql shell]

```
BEGIN; SELECT PG_SLEEP(5); SELECT NOW(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP(), STATEMENT_TIMESTAMP(); COMMIT;
```

I got this output:

```
              now              |       current_timestamp       |     transaction_timestamp     |      statement_timestamp
-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------
 2019-04-23 11:15:18.676855-04 | 2019-04-23 11:15:18.676855-04 | 2019-04-23 11:15:18.676855-04 | 2019-04-23 11:15:23.713275-04
(1 row)
```

You can see clearly that `NOW`, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, `TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP` are equivalent, and `STATEMENT_TIMESTAMP` has a 5 second offset because we slept for 5 seconds.

BTW, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is in the sql standard. The others are postgresql specific, *though other databases may also implement them*

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the doc your mention:

> now() is a traditional PostgreSQL equivalent to
>   transaction_timestamp().

So, they are the same, and they are here for historical / backward compatibility, and some could argue for the simplicity of the function name.